# setting asp:CheckBox as checked in code behind in asp:FormView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I don't know if this is even possible, but I am trying to set a `asp:CheckBox`, in a `FormView`, to `Checked=True` if a value in a `database = yes|no|pending etc`...

here is the code behind (in a PreRender Sub):

```
    Dim rowHiredStatus As DataRowView = CType(fvRecruitInterviewed.DataItem, DataRowView)

    Dim lblTestHiredStatus As Label = CType(fvRecruitInterviewed.FindControl("lblTestHiredStatus"), Label)

    Dim chkHiredPending As CheckBox = CType(fvRecruitInterviewed.FindControl("chkHiredPending"), CheckBox)
    Dim chkHiredNo As CheckBox = CType(fvRecruitInterviewed.FindControl("chkHiredNo"), CheckBox)
    Dim chkHiredYes As CheckBox = CType(fvRecruitInterviewed.FindControl("chkHiredYes"), CheckBox)

    If Not IsNothing(rowHiredStatus) Then

        Dim strHiredStatus As String
        strHiredStatus = rowHiredStatus("HiredStatus").ToString()
        lblTestHiredStatus.Text = strHiredStatus

        If strHiredStatus = "yes" Then
            chkHiredYes.Checked = True
            lblTestHiredStatus.Text = strHiredStatus
        ElseIf (strHiredStatus = "no") Then
            chkHiredNo.Checked = True
            lblTestHiredStatus.Text = strHiredStatus
        Else
            chkHiredPending.Checked = True
            lblTestHiredStatus.Text = strHiredStatus
        End If

    End If
```

and in design view:

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHiredPending" runat="server" Text="Pending" />
    <br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHiredNo" runat="server" Text="Not Hired"/>
    <br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHiredYes" runat="server" Text="Hired" />

    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblTestHiredStatus" runat="server" />
```

the frustrating thing is that the test label displays the correct data, but the checkbox will not change.  It just defaults to the pending checkbox.

Using a `RadioButton` group or`RadioButtonList` would be fine, if that is easier/possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an question/answer on the ASP.Net forums that helped me answer my question:
[Binding CheckBoxList in FormView](http://forums.asp.net/t/1581376.aspx/1)

and I implemented it like so:

//Design View

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblHiredStatus" runat="server" DataTextField="hiredstatus" DataValueField="hiredstatus">
    <asp:ListItem Value="pending">Pending</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="no">Not Hired</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="yes">Hired</asp:ListItem>            
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

//Code Behind

```
 Dim cblHiredStatus As CheckBoxList = CType(fvRecruitInterviewed.FindControl("cblHiredStatus"), CheckBoxList)

 If cblHiredStatus IsNot Nothing Then
      Dim csv As String = DataBinder.Eval(fvRecruitInterviewed.DataItem, "HiredStatus").ToString()
      If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(csv) Then
           Dim hiredstatus As String() = csv.Split()
           For Each str As String In hiredstatus
                If cblHiredStatus.Items.FindByValue(str) IsNot Nothing Then
                     cblHiredStatus.Items.FindByValue(str).Selected = True
                End If
           Next
      End If
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description of the problem and the code, I am willing to go out on a limb and say the problem is the value of strHiredStatus.

Since Pending is getting checked, we know that the code is getting fired and in the code, pending is the default clause in the If statement, which means that the issue must be with the test of strHiredStatus.

When you test a string with equals, it is a case-sensitive test. This means that "Yes" is not the same as "yes".

There are different ways to solve this problem, but my preferred way is to use the [String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx) method with case and culture insensitivity:

```
If strHiredStatus.Equals("yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
    chkHiredYes.Checked = True
    lblTestHiredStatus.Text = strHiredStatus
ElseIf strHiredStatus.Equals("no", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
```

The reason for the culture insensitivity (which I have been burned by previously), is that if you have a string constant and just convert the constant string to lower case, you will get unexpected results when running internationally.

For example, when running in a Turkish environment, an upper case I will not be converted to an English lower-case i, it will be converted to a Turkish i (not sure what the correct name for the character is, but is a different character).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but its still only working for the test label (and pending being checked).

Comment: @IanMitz: What does the test label say?

Comment: whatever the relevant field is in the db.  i.e. yes, no or pending (lblTestHiredStatus.Text = strHiredStatus)